# could I ignore the memory leak information related to " __wcslen_sse2" in valgrind memcheck report

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I am now using valgrind and memcheck to detect the potential memory leak in my program, and in the report I found the following information:

```
Invalid read of size 8
     at Ox4310557: __wcslen_sse2 (wcslen-sse2.S:85)
      by myclass:perform_functionality( **.cpp:59)
      by 0x8074656: main (main.cpp:83)
   Address 0x4a46530 is 8 bytes after a block of size 176 alloc'd
      at 0x402B9B4: operator new(unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
     by 0x420B386: std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t>   >::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned int, unsigned int, std::allocator<wchar_t> const&) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
     by 0x420C68F: std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >::_Rep::_M_clone(std::allocator<wchar_t> const&, unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
     by 0x420C7BD: std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t>>::reserve(unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16)
  by 0xE29AFF: ???
```

and

```
Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised values(s)
  at 0x4310578:  __wcslen_sse2 (wcslen-sse.s:95)
```

It is very difficult, however, to figure out where the leak is. It seems the message is related to std::string, but I am not sure.The memory usage summary is as follows:

```
HEAP SUMMARY:
==2302==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2302==   total heap usage: 87,293 allocs, 87,293 frees, 427,491,963 bytes allocated
```

So my question is: should I ignore the message related to  __wcslen_sse2? Thanks.

**EDIT:**
  I found all the message will disappear if I remove the following codes in the function:

```
std::cout<<"Writing....."<<std::endl;
std::wcout<<imageFileName.c_str()<<std::endl;
```

This confirms my guess that this kind of message comes from `std::wstring`. So why calling `.c_str()` will intriguer these messages? By the way, imageFileName is of class member variable, which is set before using this class.

Comment: The first error could be because of you passing illegal arguments to the function.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks, and I am not sure I understand you. So I edit my question and put more information on the first error.

Comment: Regarding the first error, what are you passing for arguments to the __wcslen_sse2` function? A `std::wstring` object? A `wchar_t` pointer? A `char` pointer? Something else? And how do you initialize the argument you pass? Some code would be better.

Comment: Which part of your question is about a "leak"?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks for the comments. The problem is that I do not know where wcslen function is called. I use std::wstring as a class member variable, which is supposed to be set before using this class. I also edited the question and put some codes as you suggested.